# Access parent object from inside object

Tags: javascript, object, prototypejs

I was wondering if there's an elegant way of doing the following code instead of having to call the parent object "that" first. If I try using "this" from within the ajax request it'll obviously refer to the Ajax object.

At least that's what I think it means.

```
var ObjectA = Class.create();

ObjectA.prototype = {
  initialize: function() {
  //Workaround I use
  that = this;
  },

getData: function(bounds) {
  //ajax to get some data       
  url = "http://www.data.com/";     

  new Ajax.Request(url, {
    method: 'get',
    onSuccess: function(response) {
    // Handle the response content...
    that.workData(response.responseText);
    //THIS IS MY DOUBT.
    //How do I access the parent object without having to previously calling it "that" first?
    }
  });

},
workData: function(data){
//do something with the data
}

} 

var test = new ObjectA();
test.getData();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well .. `that` is not accessible inside of `getData` to begin with since it's a different scope than `initialize`.  It's very common to rename `this` so it can be used in inner scope contexts, and you may end up wanting to use whatever `this` is supposed to be in the `onSuccess` context anyway, but since you asked:

```
onSuccess: function (response) {
    //this is now ObjectA
}.bind(this);
```

In action: http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/hY3Ca/

Comment: That's the only I had it working so far. I'll try your suggestion! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`bind()`](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/language/Function/prototype/bind/):

```
...
onSuccess: function(response) {
   this.workData(response.responseText);
}.bind(this)
...
```